# Logging errors to console

Tags: reactjs, components, console.log

I want to log any errors I am getting to the console and I have been getting this warning when I try to run my tests:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
>           in ErrorDialog (at ErrorDialog.test.js:36)
>           in WrapperComponent

This is what I have for my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import log from '../pathtologlevel';
import ErrorContext from '../pathtoErrorContext';

class Error extends React.Component {
 static type = ErrorContext;

 constructor(props, context) {
   super(props, context);
   this.state = { err: null };
   this.processError = this.processError.bind(this);
   this.list= [];
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   const errorService = this.context;
   errorService.attach((err) => {
     log.info('changing state');
     this.array.push(err);
     this.processError();
   });
 }

 processError() {
   const { err } = this.state;
   log.info('processNextError', this.array.length, err);
   if (!err && this.array.length > 0) {
     log.info('Displaying next error');
     this.setState({ err: this.array.shift() });
   }
 }

 render() {
   const { err } = this.state;
   log.info(err);
   if (err) {
     return this.processError;
   }
   return null;
 }
}

export default Error;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the function `this.processError` instead of calling it in the render method. Just call the function `this.processError()` and you should not be getting any warnings.

Comment: When I change it to '''this.processError()''' I now get the error '''Error: Uncaught [Error: Error(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.]'''

Comment: If you are creating the react component, render expects you to return something such as some components/string/null etc. Inside the processError you are not returning anything which is causing the error. Just add return null inside processError and it should be fine

Comment: A better condition can be to call function and then return null instead of return this.processError like: `if (err) { this.processError(); return null } return null`